# TinyMCE : How to apply a style to several selected items?

Tags: javascript, tinymce

I'm using TinyMCE and I'd like to be able to apply styles on several selected items.

When I make multiple selections holding [ctrl] and apply a style on these selected items, only the first one gets the style.

Is it possible to apply the style on each selected item ?

I know that CKEditor is able to do this.

Comment: By holding control, i selected multiple sections of a paragraph. The clicked on B(bold) and it worked. Which browser are you testing this on?

Comment: http://www.tinymce.com/tryit/basic.php
On FF 24, multiple selections by holding [ctrl] is possible but Bold style only applies to first selection.
On Chrome 18, multiple selections with [ctrl] is even impossible.

Comment: Did you find any solution? I'm also have this bug.

Comment: Hi, unfortunately, I did not find any solution.